# How do you get Count R2 in R (with missing data)?

Tags: r, prediction, goodness-of-fit

I am doing binary logistic regression in R and I need to calculate the Count R squared for various model specifications. Count R2 is the number of correctly predicted observations using the model divided by the total number of observations. It measures how well the model predicts the correct value of the dependent variable, using known values. I'm planning to use the model for prediction, so the percent of observations that are predicted correctly would be really useful for me. Creating a classification table is difficult because I have missing data, so the fitted table and the original table have different numbers of records. I'm pretty inexperienced with R, so I don't know if there's a straightforward way to get around that.

My specific question is:

Is there a command in R to get the Count R2, (and better yet, the adjusted count R2)?

If not, is there an easy way to get R to put the predicted probabilities and the original dependent variable in a table together, when there are different numbers of records? This would allow me to calculate the Count R2 myself.

Comment: By R2 do you mean $R^2$, the coefficient of determination? I've never heard the term count $R^2$, how is that defined? In any case, you should use a different metric for model comparison than $R^2$ with logistic regression. See [this post](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/why-is-there-no-r-squared-for-nonlinear-regression) for why.

Comment: Note: the OP defines the term in question, "percent of observations that are predicted correctly".

Comment: Also, he says that "percent of observations predicted correctly would be useful" not that that metric is how he's defining this "count $R^2$".

Comment: I think you mean these terms as defined [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/Psuedo_RSquareds.htm), correct? You should be able to compare, e.g. `round(fitted.values(m))` and `na.omit(y)`. But to really answer you question, we need a reproducible example to work with.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. I was able to successfully create a classification table using `na.omit(y)`. Although I would prefer a command that just gives me count r2, this will work.

Comment: @dichotomy This can be done with the one liner `mean(na.omit(y)==round(fitted.values(m)))`.

Comment: You will have the idea of "Count R square" in Guajarati, Basic Econometrics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a logistic regression with a binary response from "A Handbook of Statistical Analyses Using R".

```
library(HSAUR)

#modify plasma data set to have an NA for illustrative purposes
plasma2<-plasma
plasma2[10,1]<-NA

#fit logistic binary response model
m2 <- glm(ESR ~ fibrinogen + globulin, data = plasma2,family=binomial())
```

You can calculate count R-squared with a one-liner

```
countR2<-function(m) mean(m$y==round(m$fitted.values))

countR2(m2)
#=>[1] 0.8709677
```

For the adjusted count R-squared

```
adj.countR2<-function(m) {
  n<-length(m$y)
      k<-max(table(m$y))
  correct<-table(m$y==round(m$fitted.values))[["TRUE"]]
  (correct-k)/(n-k)
}

adj.countR2(m2)
#=>[1] 0.3333333
```

Also useful is to produce the confusion matrix, from which both could also be easily calculated.

```
confusion.matrix<-function(m) 
  addmargins(table(m$y,round(m$fitted.values),dnn=c("Actual","Predicted")))

confusion.matrix(m2)
#=>
```

```
      Predicted
Actual  0  1 Sum
   0   25  0  25
   1    4  2   6
   Sum 29  2  31
```